# Data no longer saves to table in my SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have two tables in my database, users and players.
User register/login and add players.
The user id is the foreign key used in the players table.
My code was working fine and saving everything perfectly.
However i had an issue with my emulator where it kept crashing, so i wiped its memory and re-ran my app.
Now i have an issue where when i register/login and add a player, the code runs through and looks fine in debug mode but its table in the database never gets populated

Im so furious with this as it was working 100% fine until i wiped its memory.
Could anyone please offer some support?

## Code

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database information
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB1.db";
private static final String TABLE_USER = "User";
private static final String TABLE_PLAYERS = "Player";
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

// Field names for Users
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "User_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "User_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "User_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "User_password";


// Field names for Players
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME = "Player_name";
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_AGE = "Player_age";
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_WEIGHT = "Player_weight";
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_HEIGHT = "Player_height";
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_ID = "Player_id";
public static final String FOREIGN_PLAYER_ID = COLUMN_USER_ID;
// private static final Image COLUMN_PLAYER_IMAGE ;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[]{COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME, COLUMN_PLAYER_AGE, COLUMN_PLAYER_HEIGHT, COLUMN_PLAYER_WEIGHT};

// Table 1 : Login/Register
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";


// Table 2 : Adding players
private String CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYERS + "(" + COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_PLAYER_AGE + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_PLAYER_WEIGHT + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_PLAYER_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + FOREIGN_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER," + "FOREIGN KEY(" + FOREIGN_PLAYER_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_USER + "(User_id) " + ")";


// Drop tables

private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
private String DROP_PLAYER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAYERS;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    //String name,  SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}

public DatabaseHelper open() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(DROP_PLAYER_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}


// Adding a user to Users table
public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // Table 1 : Add users info
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
    values.put(FOREIGN_PLAYER_ID, user.getForeignID());

    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close();
}

// Adding a player to players table

public void addPlayer(Player player) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    // Table 2 : Add players info
    values.put(COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME, player.getPlayerName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PLAYER_AGE, player.getPlayerAge());
    values.put(COLUMN_PLAYER_HEIGHT, player.getPlayerHeight());
    values.put(COLUMN_PLAYER_WEIGHT, player.getPlayerWeight());
    values.put("Foreign_id", player.getForeignKey());

    db.insert(TABLE_PLAYERS, null, values);
    db.close();

}

// Checking the users email
public boolean checkUser(String email) {
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID

    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//
public String getColumnUserName(String email) {

    String user = "";
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID

    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    String[] b = cursor.getColumnNames();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // data?{
        user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("User_id"));

    cursor.close(); // that's important too, otherwise you're gonna leak cursors
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return user;
    }
    return user;
}

// Checking the users email and password
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID

    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public Cursor getAllRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //String query = "SELECT * from "+TABLE_PLAYERS;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select  Player_id _id, * from Player"  , null);


    return cursor;
}
```

}

AddPlayers.java

```
public class addPlayers extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 View.OnClickListener {

private Button insert;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

private final AppCompatActivity activity = addPlayers.this;


private EditText editTextPlayerName;
private EditText editTextPlayerAge;
private EditText editTextPlayerWeight;
private EditText editTextPlayerHeight;

private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
private Inputvalidation inputvalidation;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private Player player;
private Button appCompatButtonRegister;
private User user;

DatabaseHelper myDb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_players);
    // insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    // insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    //getPlayersInformationListView();

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    initViews();
    initListeners();
    initObjects();


}

private void initViews() {


    editTextPlayerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerName);
    editTextPlayerAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerAge);
    editTextPlayerHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerHeight);
    editTextPlayerWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerWeight);
    textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
    appCompatButtonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savePlayer);

}

private void initListeners() {

    appCompatButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initObjects() {

    inputvalidation = new Inputvalidation(activity);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    player = new Player();

}

// Table 2 : Add players info

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
    //startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.savePlayer:
            postDataToSQLite();
            break;

    }


}


private void postDataToSQLite() {


    if (!databaseHelper.checkUser(editTextPlayerName.getText().toString().trim()))
    //textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim()))
    {
        Bundle email = getIntent().getExtras();
        String a = databaseHelper.getColumnUserName(email.getString("EMAIL"));

        player.setPlayerName(editTextPlayerName.getText().toString().trim());
        player.setPlayerAge(Integer.parseInt(editTextPlayerAge.getText().toString().trim()));
        player.setPlayerHeight(Integer.parseInt(editTextPlayerHeight.getText().toString().trim()));
        player.setPlayerWeight(Integer.parseInt(editTextPlayerWeight.getText().toString().trim()));
        player.setForeignKey(Integer.parseInt(a));


        databaseHelper.addPlayer(player);

        Intent accountIntent = new Intent(activity, Players.class);
        startActivity(accountIntent);





    }





}
```

}

Players.java

```
 public class Players extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button insert;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
private String nameFromIntent = "";
DatabaseHelper myDb;

ListView playersList;
ArrayList<String> listItem;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_players);

    openDB();
    getAllRows();

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //Open add players section
    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlayer);
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)

        {
            openAddPlayersActivity();


        }

    });

}

private void openDB() {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    myDb.open();
}

private void closeDB() {
    myDb.close();
}

private void getAllRows() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of cursor
    // Deprecated
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PLAYER_AGE, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PLAYER_WEIGHT, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PLAYER_HEIGHT};


    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.textView01, R.id.textView02, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6};

    // Create Adapter to map columns of DB onto elements in the UI
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.player_layout, cursor , fromFieldNames , toViewIDs);


    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playersList);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}

private void openAddPlayersActivity(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, addPlayers.class);
    String nameFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
    intent.putExtra(("EMAIL"), nameFromIntent);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

}

Comment: This may be strange and it may or may not work for you, but I had a similar issue in the past. Try changing the db name and see if that fixes your issue...

Comment: Have you logged and seen if your Database helper class works as intended. Especially, the onCreate method. Also, try changing the Database version and running your code. I'd suggest you look into [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), it is [recommended by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) and is safer (less error prone) and easier to use than SQLite directly. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKWh4ckvFPM) youtube on Room by Android Developer channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are trying to add players using the **User_name** for the **User_id** column (the FK) rather than the referenced User_id. This then results in something along the lines of :-

```
04-12 08:25:34.782 13798-13798/aaa.so55497937 E/SQLiteLog: (787) abort at 16 in [INSERT INTO Player(Player_age,Player_name,User_id,Player_weight,Player_height) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)]: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
04-12 08:25:34.783 13798-13798/aaa.so55497937 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Player_age=21 Player_name=Fred User_id=FRED Player_weight=75 Player_height=160
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at aaa.so55497937.DatabaseHelper.addPlayer(DatabaseHelper.java:125)
```

i.e. User_id=FRED will not correlate to any value in the referenced User_ID column in the user table (which due to being defined using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will always be a number *(P.S. AUTOINCREMENT is not needed and is actually wasteful of resources [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html))*)

That is you set the ForeignID for the player using :-

```
String a = databaseHelper.getColumnUserName(email.getString("EMAIL"));
```

Whilst you should be setting **a** to the user_id column of the User. So perhaps add the method :-

```
public String getColumnUserId(String email) {
    String rv = "";
    String[] columns = {COLUMN_USER_ID};
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

and then use :-

```
String a = databaseHelper.getColumnUserId(email.getString("EMAIL"));
```

Perhaps note that if things aren't working as expected, especially with SQLite, that you should check the log (i.e. although logged, the error is trapped and ignored and thus does not crash).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are passing wrong Models in DatabaseHelper class.

```
public void addUser(User user){

//code..

}

public void add player(Player player){  
/* Are you sure you have created Player.java model?? Because you have another class Players.java too. And check for User.java model too..
another thing, make sure your model have default constructors. */

//code..

}
```